# I need a std function which checks how many elements occur exactly once in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Is there any STL function which does this?
For vector:

```
4 4 5 5 6 7
```

The expected output should be `2`,because of one `6 and 7`

Would you be kind to help me count them classic if there is no STL function?

Comment: The question is not so clear. You want to count the number of elements that occur once in the vector, right? "How many of one element" could also be counting how many `4`s are there...

Comment: Your title is wrong then, you probably meant "How many elements occur exactly once".

Comment: Is you vector sorted ?

Comment: One approach would be std::sort, followed by std::unique then count the remaining elements. There might be a faster C++ standard library approach than this though: you could bung the elements into a set and count the number of elements.

Comment: Do you expect the output should be 3 for 4 4 5 5 5 6 7? Question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks working on it

Comment: @ShivendraMishra still `2`

Comment: copy the vector to a multiset then check counts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an algorithm for that in STL. You can copy into a `multimap` or use a `map` of frequencies as suggested, but it does extra work that's not necessary because your array happens to be sorted. Here is a simple algorithm that counts the number of singular elements i.e. elements that appear only once in a sorted sequence.

```
int previous = v.front();
int current_count = 0;
int total_singular = 0;
for(auto n : v) {
    if(previous == n)          // check if same as last iteration
        current_count++;       // count the elements equal to current value
    else {
        if(current_count == 1) // count only those that have one copy for total
            total_singular++;
        previous = n;
        current_count = 1;     // reset counter, because current changed
    }
}
if(current_count == 1)         // check the last number
    total_singular++;
```

You could also use `count_if` with a stateful lambda, but I don't think it'll make the algorithm any simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If performance and memory doesn't matter to you, use `std::map` (or unordered version) for this task:

```
size_t count(const std::vector<int>& vec){
    std::map<int,unsigned int> occurenceMap;
    for (auto i : vec){
        occurenceMap[i]++;
    }

    size_t count = 0U;
    for (const auto& pair : occurenceMap){
        if (pair.second == 1U){
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

with templates, it can be generalize to any container type and any containee type.

Comment: choose one : memory or speed, they are commonly orthogenal.

Comment: @user5058813 even if speed and memory matters, it is better to use what you have and only optimize if really needed. Honestly I doubt that this is a bottleneck in your program.

Comment: @tobi303 It is also important to not pessimize your code prematurely. This solution is poor in terms of memory footprint, speed and the number of lines of code required. Modern CPUs are bottlenecked by memory speed, rather than instructions throughput, hence the more memory you use the slower your code runs. Red-black trees are also one of the least cache-friendly data structures.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin don't be passimistic yourself. you can configurare map allocator to allocate chunks from the stack, removing incremently not-unique nodes from the map. this way, the solution becomes very memory efficient. if `vec` is const you can't sort it, and if it's huge array - copying it will casue huge memory impact. so every solution has its pros and cons.

Comment: @DavidHaim Do not tell grown men what to do, that will get you in trouble. And your logic is faulty. Red-black trees are one of the least cache-friendly data structures because it involves chasing pointers which leads to cache misses. If the vector cannot be changed, it is still cheaper to copy it and sort than create a red-black tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::unique to count the unique entries(ct_u) and then user vector count on the original one (ct_o). Difference ct_o-ct_u would give the answer.

P.S.: this will only work if the identical entries are together in the original vector. If not, you may want to sort the vector first.

Comment: sorry I missed this.

Comment: I removed my comment because I don't think my example input was one with wrong result. `{1, 2, 2, 2}` is an example that wouldn't work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using algorithm:

```
std::size_t count_unique(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::size_t count = 0;

    for (auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); )
    {
        auto it2 = std::find_if(it + 1, v.end(), [&](int e) { return e != *it; });
        count += (it2 - it == 1);
        it = it2;
    }
    return count;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/91BQYD)